# What are the pros and cons of using a PropertyChangeListener vs. using LocalBroadcastReceivers?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, propertychangelistener, propertychangesupport

It seems like property change listeners are better than sending broadcasts because you can pass objects back to the property listeners whereas when you broadcast an Intent, it can only contain primitives or Parcelable objects. However, I'm not sure how well the objects passed in property change listeners are garbage collected, etc. Could anyone provide some insight for best practices regarding the use of both?